# How to transform oscillating data

Tags: transformation

I have data that looks like the following image, but reversed, starting small and increasing over time. All of the data is currently in a csv file, with time being one column and the values being another. I was wondering what transformations would be possible in order to use the data and discover trends or a relationship. Thank you!                                                                      [image]

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. This platform may not be suitable for this question.

Comment: agreed, could we see some sample data? what kind of transformations are you talking about? I think this question is more about "what are different ways to identify trends/relationships in graph data"